# Need help to login to Vimeo using google signin

Tags: android, vimeo

I'm building an app using **vimeo developer apis**. I didn't find any document related to **google signin** in vimeo developer apis. I want to let user signin using google in vimeo.

I need to login to **Vimeo** using google account. I don’t know which API to hit after I receive **IDToken** from google api.

Can some body help here.

**Note:** I find document about Authenticating app using Vimeo account.

Comment: this site is about code problems, you need to post the code that you tried, the expected result compared to the actual result.  Please do some research and post back with what you tried.

Comment: @JKing My question is not related to coding problem. I need a clarification about linking google account with vimeo account. Can you point me to right place if this is not right place.

Comment: Vimeo support? https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us

Comment: @cricket_007 Nope. I'm building an app using vimeo developer apis. I didn't find any document related to google signin in vimeo developer apis. I want to let user signin using google in vimeo

Comment: There is a "Contact Us" button there.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Google/Facebook single sign-on can only be used on the Vimeo website or the Vimeo Android and iOS apps; single sign-on is not open to public use.

You'll need to authenticate your Vimeo account by going through the OAuth workflow, or generating a personal access token on the Vimeo developer site. An overview of these methods can be found here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication

Comment: Thanks for reply. I noted it.